# fckeditor copy paste disabled for Firefox and Chrome

Tags: firefox, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, fckeditor, cfml

I have and internal admin site that is used only by our people.  For the most part they use Firefox ( that's the standard for the site anyway).  We use Coldfusion 9 for development and have quite a few `<cftextarea>` tags.  I seem to have lost touch with whatever controls the clipboard events.  But, they have been disabled.  I'm just guessing,  but it seems like FF 42 seems to be the culprit when using the CF9 fckeditor.  I could convert to another editor but that's a pretty big task.

I've been researching but can't find any clear instructions on setting security policies in FF.  I need suggestions.  I'm just about to try changing the tag from `<cftextarea>` to textarea but I know I'm going to run into problems getting getting richtext functions.

Comment: Same here, I am using old fckeditor verstion. "Past from Word" button is disabled. Was fine up untill FF42 (may be 41, not sure). Other browsers have no this problem.

Comment: I got the same issue with FF41 on Win7 and Mac

Answer (score 2):

If you want to enable paste functionality icons you can alter following function:

```
var FCKToolbarButton = function(A, B, C, D, E, F, G) {
console.log(A, B, C, D, E, F, G);
this.CommandName = A;
this.Label = B;
this.Tooltip = C;
this.Style = D;
this.SourceView = true; //E ? true : false;
this.ContextSensitive = false; //F ? true : false;
if (G == null) this.IconPath = FCKConfig.SkinPath + 'toolbar/' + A.toLowerCase() + '.gif';
else if (typeof(G) == 'number') this.IconPath = [FCKConfig.SkinPath + 'fck_strip.gif', 16, G];
else this.IconPath = G;
};
```

and change

```
this.ContextSensitive = F ? true : false;
```

to

```
this.ContextSensitive = false;
```

You can find this function in FCKeditor/editor/js/fckeditorcode_gecko.js and FCKeditor/editor/js/fckeditorcode_ie.js

It's not best solution but it works.

Comment: I'm not seeing any differences after making the changes. There is only one instance of the file. I've been looking for some place in the code where I can add an "x" so that I can tell if I'm using the changed code or not.  Not easy.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by a changed security behavior in Firefox 41 and later.

You have to modify the following lines in `fckeditorcode_gecko.js`. Add "`|| FCKBrowserInfo.IsGecko`" in the following lines (marked bold). After that the paste buttons are always active and pasting something will always open up a paste window (it's the same behavior ckeditor uses).

```
GetNamedCommandState:function(A){try{if ((FCKBrowserInfo.IsSafari **|| FCKBrowserInfo.IsGecko**)&&FCK.EditorWindow&&A.IEquals('Paste')) return 0;
```

...

```
FCK.RedirectNamedCommands={Print:true,Paste:true};FCK.ExecuteRedirectedNamedCommand=function(A,B){switch (A){case 'Print':FCK.EditorWindow.print();break;case 'Paste':try{if (FCKBrowserInfo.IsSafari **|| FCKBrowserInfo.IsGecko**) throw '';
```

Comment: When would the changes be active?  I'm not seeing any differences with this patch either.

Comment: For me it works changing just the "GetNamedCommandState" part in file fckplugin.js

Comment: This should be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The changes are active instantaniously but Firefox sometimes does not reload changed Javascript files.  In that case you should delete your browser history  completely and then reload the editor.

Answer (score 0):

The only option available is to convert to CKeditor and stop using  tags.  However, CKeditor has problems running under CFlayout tags.  What a complete cludge of crap!  The real solution is to get completely away from Coldfusion/Adobe.  I don't have a suggestion, but I will be researching.